# Material.tres uses an old deprecated parameters names?

Tags: godot, godot-shader-language

### Problem:

I have a material which uses a shader in godot4(first stable release) and this is the code for the shader:

```
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform sampler2D custom_texture;
uniform float cutoff: hint_range(0, 1) = 1;
uniform float smoothness: hint_range(0, 1) = 0.1;
uniform vec3 color = vec3(0, 0, 0);
uniform bool inverted = false;
uniform bool linear_fade = true;

void fragment() {
    if (!linear_fade) {
        float value = texture(custom_texture, UV).r;
        if (inverted) {
            value = 1.0 - value;
        }
        float alpha = smoothstep(cutoff, cutoff + smoothness, value * (1.0 - smoothness) + smoothness);
        COLOR = vec4(color.rgb, alpha);
    } else {
        COLOR = vec4(color.rgb, (1.0 - cutoff));
    }
}
```

After I run my game scene with this shader attached to a color rect, I get this warning message multiple times:

```
W 0:00:01:0839   _set: This material (containing shader with path: 'res://addons/scene_manager/scene_manager.tres::Shader_vksmm') uses an old deprecated parameter names. Consider re-saving this resource (or scene which contains it) in order for it to continue working in future versions.
  <C++ Source>   scene/resources/material.cpp:184 @ _set()
```

If you want to actually create this error message by yourself and see what is happening, you can clone [scene_manager](https://github.com/maktoobgar/scene_manager) repository(which is an addon for godot) and run its demo to see the original problem I'm dealing with.

Thanks everyone who is helping me on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Before Answering

Someone actually answered the question but not in here, answer is in [this github issue thread](https://github.com/maktoobgar/scene_manager/issues/5#issuecomment-1452156083) of scene manager project and all credits to that guy.

#### Actual Answer

problem is not related to shader code or material or even the ColorRect, that I mentioned in the question, but it is instead related to an **AnimationPlayer** that I had into my scene that was changing some variables of my shader code.

Take a look at this:
[image: godot4 parameter problem]

Take a look at the parameter name that is mentioned on the left side:

`material:shader_param/cutoff`

All you have to do is to change the `param` part to `parameter`. like this:

`material:shader_parameter/cutoff`

Apply this for all of your other animations and problem solved.

@LukeDaDuke